# Angular 2 extension discovery

Tags: angular, modular-design

We have an Angular 2 app with a .NET backend. Both ends should support installation of additional external modules to be "installed".

That is, an external module can provide:

1. A new menu item
2. A new screen
3. New RESTful endpoints
4. Some metadata, that the core backend platform uses to provide authorization, etc...

I was wondering how a new route with a new screen written in Angular can be injected into our app so this new module or extension would be automatically discovered after installation and the menu item would appear as well. Obviously, we'd like that without having to recompile the entire application (Angular frontend or C# backend).

I plan to package extensions as a .zip file that contains different folders for .NET DLLs, angular frontend components and some XML metadata that the installation would need.

Any tips or solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible .The problem is not only in Angular but in a way it's bundled. It would likely be doable with SystemJS alone, but it isn't suited well for production. Webpack is a different story. Building the app into several UMD bundles and joining it together with SystemJS would probably a suitable compromise, yet the size may increase considerably. Making build script a part of 'installation' process would probably be most natural for the framework.